# Nuxt generate head function not working in second level routes

Tags: nuxt.js, head, vue-meta

I have struggling with `head()` method in child pages. You can see my file structure in image. `index.vue` is perfectly working with `head()` method. But the other pages are taking `index.vue` head definitions when I use `nuxt generate`.

My configuration is `ssr: true` and `target: static`. I tried many things and spent so much time to solve this issue. I didn't find proper solution for this.

[image]

`index.vue` `head` section:

```
head: {
  title: 'Features',
},
```

`couriers.vue` `head` section:

```
head() {
  return {
    title: 'Couriers',
  };
},
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I found the problem. I added html sitemap to my web site by retrieving routes from `nuxt router`. And I made some logic to show the list in good shape. Somehow this operations breaks the generating logic of nuxt. In my logic, I just iterating the routes array and create a new array which has parent child associated. But child pages always taking parent head structure when I use `nuxt generate`. So I removed the child pages from my html sitemap array and it's working as I expected. Now I'm trying to find a solution for how to add child pages into my html sitemap page. I hope I'll find.

Comment: why is the first head an object and the second one an function? did you try it by making both an function?

Comment: Yes I tried. I just wanted to show I can use both.